# Referring to nested arrays and array_merge (php)

Tags: php, array, php5

In such an array:

```
$arr = Array (
    [key0] => Array (
        [subkey0] => Array (
            [0] => "value0"
            [1] => "value1"
        )
        [subkey1] => Array (
            [0] => "value0"
            [1] => "value1"
        )
    )
    [key1] => Array (
        [subkey0] => Array (
            [0] => "value0"
            [1] => "value1"
        )
        [subkey1] => Array (
            [0] => "value0"
            [1] => "value1"
        )
    )
)
```

In order to add $varX to the end of $arr[keyX][subkeyX] as [X] => $varX, I use, inside a loop, the following:

```
$arr[$key] = array(
    "subkey0" => array_merge((array)$arr[$key]["subkey0"], (array)$var1),
    "subkey1" => array_merge((array)$arr[$key]["subkey1"], (array)$var2)
    ...
)
```

And I might be working with even more nested arrays, so I was wondering if there was a way for `subkey0` to refer to itself, or if I could do something like:

```
"subkeyX" =>+ (array)$varX
```

Or use `array_merge()` in a different way to add `$varX` to the end of `subkeyX` as `[X] => $varX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the question right. But this should work.

```
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $arr2[$key]['subkey0'][] = $var1;
    $arr2[$key]['subkey1'][] = $var2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to work. For instance, check [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e95-3tr) -- click on run to see the results.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not clear enough. I edited it.